# Project image onto inside of sphere with Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, projection, geometry-surface

### Problem:

Let's say I have a large image, 5000x3000 pixels. I want to paste this image onto the inside of a sphere of some arbitrary radius.

To do this I will import the image as an array and I will determine the centre of the array. I will loop through each pixel, determining how far displaced it is from the centre, and using this x and y displacement I will use simple geometry to determine where it should be copied to on an output array.

Below are some examples of what my inputs and outputs are (but on a far smaller scale than I am trying to use).

**Example Input**

[image: Example input image]

**Example Output**

[image: Example output image]

How can I speed up my method, which being pixel by pixel over a very large array, takes minutes, using python and numpy?

---

### Code:

```
(x_d, y_d, z_d) = image.shape #get image dimensions
(x_c, y_c) = (x_d/2.0, y_d/2.0) #determine centre of image
new_image = np.zeros([x_m, y_m, d]) #create empty output image

for x in range(0, x_d): #iterate across pixels
    for y in range(0, y_d): #iterate down pixels
        (x_1, y_1) = (x-x_c, y-y_c) #determine pixel displacement from centre
        (r_x, r_y) = (np.sqrt((rad**2.0)-(y_1**2.0)), np.sqrt((rad**2.0)-(x_1**2.0))) #determine relative radius (maths part 2)
        #determine the relative radius
        x_2 = int(np.round(r_x*np.sin(x_1/r_x), 0)) #determine new x-position (maths part 1)
        y_2 = int(np.round(r_y*np.sin(y_1/r_y), 0)) #determine new y-position (maths part 1)
        x_2 = int(np.round(x_2+x_c, 0)) #convert back to absolute pixel location
        y_2 = int(np.round(y_2+y_c, 0)) #convert back to absolute pixel location
        new_image[x_2, y_2, :] = image[x, y, :] #...place the pixel there
```

---

### Attempts:

I have searched for pre-built libraries to do this, but I struggle with some of the specific terminology and haven't found anything yet.

I have tried reading and writing array values using numpy's item and itemset functions, but that actually seems to slow down the processing.

Since I will be running this over multiple images I have tried generating the transformation array first, but this has only a very small impact on run times. ie:

```
def generate_array(array, rad):
    """
    Function takes image and returns array that can be used to warp it
    """
    #array generated as code above but saved to 2 dimensional array for resultant x and y locations
    return array

def spherize(image, array):
    """
    Function takes image and warps it up as defined by the array
    """
    #image processed as code above but maths is not performed, instead output x and y locations are read from previously generated array
    return new_image
```

---

### Maths:

[image: Image explaining maths part 1 referred to in the code]
*Image explaining "maths part 1" as referred to in the code.* This gets the resultant pixel location as if seen from the top of the sphere on which the image has been pasted. This works in one dimension should the radius remain the same in the other dimension, however for a sphere this effective radius changes since the circle drawn out on the inside of the sphere becomes smaller the further away you are from the centre. As such "maths part 2" finds the effective radius of the circle drawn out on the inside of the sphere in x given a displacement from the centre of the sphere in y.

[image: Image explaining maths part 2 referred to in the code]
*Image explaining "maths part 2" as referred to in the code.* This finds the effective radius with which to calculate resultant x location based on the displacement from the centre of the sphere in y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having trouble following the logic in the code you've shared. It would help if you showed where the image is located in your diagrams and if you could provide a small example of the correct mapping of the original image points to the new image points (maybe for a 10x10 image).

That being said, I think you can speed up the calculations by using the [universal functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) of arrays. These functions preform element-wise calculations on the entire array using optimized code.

For example, you can use the `indices` function to create an array containing the indices (x and y coordinates) of each of the pixels in the image and then do all of your calculations on that.

Here's a version of your code using the array calculations. This should run much faster than looping over all of the pixels.

```
(x_d, y_d, z_d) = (10,10,3) #image.shape #get image dimensions
(x_c, y_c) = (x_d/2.0, y_d/2.0) #determine centre of image
new_image = np.zeros([x_m, y_m, z_d]) #create empty output image

x, y = np.indices( (x_d, y_d) ) #create an array with the x and y coordintes of the pixels

# determine pixel displacement from centre
x1 = x - x_c
y1 = y - y_c

#determine relative radius (maths part 2)
rx = np.sqrt(rad**2 - y1**2)
ry = np.sqrt(rad**2 - x1**2)

#determine new x-position (maths part 1)
x2 = rx*np.sin(x1/rx)+x_c
y2 = ry*np.sin(y1/ry)+y_c

#convert back to absolute pixel location
x2 = (np.round(x2)).astype(int)
y2 = (np.round(y2)).astype(int)

#...place the pixel there
new_image[x2, y2] = image[x,y]
```

I believe that I've recreated your calculations correctly based on your code, but without an input example I can't be sure this is correct. I hope this helps.